# Issue with onClick when attribute is string

Tags: javascript

I am appending links to a list in a for loop with an onClick function that has a different attribute each time like this:

```
$('.scrll').append('<li><a onClick="print('+id+')">'+ime+ ' ID: '+ehrID.slice(0,8)+'</a></li>');
```

print looks like this:

```
var print = function(id){
  console.log(id);
}
```

When the attribute id is a number it all works fine, but when I try to implement it with id as a string (withc look like this: "c22e1c68-0f37-45e5-9021-84f41f8d7822") I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

What can I do to fix this, or is there a better way to add onClick functions with and included attribute.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` can usually give you valid output.

Comment: @tadman — That will wrap the string in `"` which will prematurely end the `onClick` attribute's value.

Comment: @Quentin Sure, but you can always use the other quotes to define the attribute itself.

Comment: @tadman — And now they are prematurely ending the string literal being passed to `append`. Programmatically generating JavaScript in HTML in JavaScript is just  pain and best avoided.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed, and normally I'd use jQuery as per your example, just thought I'd mention that a possible, and probably *bad* first pass solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript string literals need to be quoted, and you aren't including quotes in the JavaScript you are generating.

The better approach is to not generate strings of code at all and use the jQuery `on` method (or native DOM if you were using that) to attach events.

```
const $li = $("<li />");
const $a = $("<a />")
             .on("click", print.bind(null, id))
             .text( ime + " ID: " + ehrID.slice(0,8) );
$li.append($a);
$('.scrll').append($li);
```